# Unable to resolve bare specifier 'vue-router'

Tags: vuejs3, micro-frontend

I have a micro-frontend project using vue 3. I have done yarn install and yarn serve:standalone. But I have an error like this

[image]

this is my `vue.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  lintOnSave: false,
  configureWebpack: {
    devServer: {
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      },
      disableHostCheck: true,
      sockPort: 9003,
      sockHost: "localhost",
      https: true,
      port: 9003,
    },
    externals: ["vue-router"],
  },
  filenameHashing: false,
};
```

Comment: Is it fixed. if yes please add that details here @Nico Sauza

Answer (score 0):

Did you install vue router `npm install vue-router@next` ?

Answer (score 0):

if you are not using a bundler (webpack/vue cli/vite/...) you should use router via [direct download or cdn](https://next.router.vuejs.org/installation.html)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.